# Back date Windows 2012 server to use program on another date

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2012-r2, erp

I have ERP application that uses the system date when posting transactions. The database is PostgreSQL. I'm able to use https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html for backdate the application but I notice that the transactions are still posting as of "today" and I think that maybe because of PostgreSQL using the system date.

Is there any way I can set the date back for PostgreSQL? Or any other way to do this? The process in the ERP application does not have an option to back date.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to add a trigger to the database that would change the date for inserted rows:

```
create table testpast(
  id serial primary key,
  time timestamp with time zone not null default now()
);

insert into testpast (time) values (default);

select * from testpast;
 id |             time              
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2018-03-16 00:09:20.219419+01
(1 row)

create function time_20_years_back() returns trigger as $$
    begin
        NEW.time = now()-'20 years'::interval;
        return NEW;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger testpast_time_20_years_back
    before insert on testpast
    for each row
    execute procedure time_20_years_back();

insert into testpast (time) values (default);

select * from testpast;
 id |             time              
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2018-03-16 00:09:20.219419+01
  2 | 1998-03-16 00:09:55.741345+01
(2 rows)
```

Though I have no idea what would be the purpose of such a hack.